# 422 HTTP Error with picker-input form in vue.js

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, http

I have a file upload form built with vue.js. The input data is packed into JSON and sent to the backend. Normally, this works successfully, I can retrieve the POSTed JSON objects with GET.

Problems arise after implementing a picker input for the file type:

```
<select class="home-select dataform dataselect" v-model="file_type">
        <option disabled value="">Select dataset type</option>
        <option v-for="type in allowedFileTypes" :value="type" :key="type.id">{{ type }}</option>
      </select>
```

The allowed file types are defined in a list in `data()` as either Indicator Matrix or Expression Matrix.

I also have a text input field for the name of the dataset.

#### The Problem

- I get a 422 error when I leave fields empty.
- I get a 422 error when I select "Expression Matrix" and fill everything else.
- I **DON'T** get a 422 error when I select "Indicator Matrix" and fill everything else.

Why does this happen and how can I fix this? I also want to be able to leave fields empty.

The total vue component looks like this:

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Showcase Page</h1>
    <select class="home-select dataform dataselect" v-model="file_type">
      <option disabled value="">Select dataset type</option>
      <option v-for="type in allowedFileTypes" :value="type" :key="type.id">{{ type }}</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter dataset name" class="input dataform" v-model="name"/>
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" @click="uploadFile">Upload</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'test',
  props: {},
  components: {},

  methods: {

    async uploadFile() {

      const response = await fetch(`${this.BASE_URL}/dataset`, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          name: this.name,
          type: this.file_type
        })
      })

      console.log("response:")
      console.log(response)
      const blob = await response.blob();
      console.log(blob)

    }
  },

  data() {
    return {
      file: new File([""], "file"),
      name: "",
      file_type: "",
      allowedFileTypes: ["Indicator Matrix", "Expression Matrix"],
      BASE_URL: process.env.VUE_APP_SERVER_URL
    }
  }
}

</script>
```

I logged the values of the variables as well as their type with `.type` and `typeof`.

- `.type` always gives *undefined*
- `typeof` always gives *string*

What does it mean that .type is always undefined, even when the input of the variable is filled?

Comment: `Why does this happen` - clearly the server requires some values that aren't being supplied in some cases - *The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) 422 Unprocessable Entity response status code indicates that the server understands the content type of the request entity, and the syntax of the request entity is correct, but it was unable to process the contained instructions.* - the solution is on the server side, to accept such empty values in your case

Comment: variables in general don't have a `.type` - some objects do ... like HTML Input Element - but your variables aren't a HTML Input Element  - also, why is the function called `uploadFile` when it doesn't upload a file?

Comment: I see, but I dont understand why the server doesn't accept empty values. Aren't they just empty strings?
Also, it doesnt accept the second option in the file-type picker input. Is it correct to store the options in a normal list in data() ?

Comment: is it your server? you tell us why, we didn't write the server code, we can't even see the server code ... also, your directive is unused, as is `selectFile` method - they seem to have something to do with `file`s at least, but at no point are you uploading a file - very odd code

Comment: also, your `allowedFileTypes` are strings, and therefore `key="type.id"` would be `undefined`

Comment: I compressed the code for this question and also left out the file upload, but these two parts I forgot to cut, I will edit them out of the question. 
What matters to me is the fetch command which posts the JSON to a URL. And I dont see why an empty input would make that fail. But what confuses me even more is that selecting the second option of file type, e.g. Expression Matrix leads it to fail.

Comment: Fair enough, so the function `uploadFile` doesn't - the 422 response is generated by the server, so it's the server code that needs to be investigated

Comment: Alright, thanks for narrowing it down.

Comment: I mean, there MAY be an error on the code you've shown, but it's not obvious without knowing what the server expects

Comment: I just found the reason for one error. I am using grails and in the File domain class I had a constraint that allowed "Numerical Matrix" but not "Expression Matrix". Really silly mistake afterall. Now I just need to find the reason why empty strings are not accepted in any field.

Answer (score 0):

I found the root of the problem:

Thanks to [Bravo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10549313/bravo) I looked into the server. That the problem lies there is of course also indicated by the 422 error. I use grails and the constraints of the File domain class are probably the reason of the errors.

I made the fields nullable and "blankable", which solved the issue.